# Topology bases for $\mathbb{R}_{\text{usual}}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to compile correctly formulated solutions to common topology questions as a summer project. I'm not very confident in my proof writing abilities so I'm going to post my solutions here for feedback and corrections:

Show explicitly that the collection $\mathcal{B} = \{ (a, b) \subseteq \Bbb{R} : a < b \}$ is basis, and that it generates the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
Solution:
In order to show that the collection $\mathcal{B}$ is a bases on $\mathbb{R}$ it needs to satisfy the following two conditions:

1. $\mathcal{B}$ covers $\Bbb{R}$
2. $\forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\forall x \in B_1 \cap B_2 \exists B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$

$\mathcal{B}$ covers $\Bbb{R}$, since for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$  we can find (a,b) $\in \mathcal{B}$ s.t $x \in (a,b)$ for example by choosing $a = x - 1$ and $b = x+1$. 
let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be any sets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $B_1 \cap B_2$ is also an open interval, and hence belongs to $\mathcal{B}$

Now to show it generates the usual topology: 
Recall the definition $$\mathbb{R}_{\text{usual}} = \{ U \subseteq \mathbb{R} : \forall x \in U \exists (x - \delta, x + \delta) \subseteq U \}.$$
We need to show that $\forall$ open sets U in $\mathbb{R}_{\text{usual}}$  and $\forall x \in \  U \ \exists \ B \in \mathcal{B} : x \in B \subseteq U$. Since $U$ is open $\exists \delta$ by definition s.t $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \subseteq U$. Since $\delta$ is arbitrary we can always find an interval (a,b) = B $\subseteq \mathcal{B}$ s.t $x \in B \subseteq U$

Comment: You have now only shown that if a set is open in $\mathbb{R}_{usual}$ it is open in the topology generated by $\{(a,b) | a<b \}$. Now you need to show the converse.

Comment: @M.Van, I edited the question slightly is this better or do I still need to show the converse ?

Comment: You need only remark that $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\text{usual}}$ to see that the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is a subset of the usual topology.

Comment: Firstly, $\delta$ is not arbitrary. Secondly, the statement you prove only states that if a set is open in $\mathbb{R}_{usual}$, then it is open in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$

Comment: @Henno $\bigcup B \in \mathcal{B}$ = $\mathbb{R_{\text usual}}$ implies that $B \subseteq \mathbb{R_{\text usual}}$ and hence $\mathcal{B}$ generates the usual topology ?